# User select input not found in Shiny app server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I'm trying to allow a user to choose a variable and create a decomposition panel based on their select, but when I try to run the app, it says **Error in eval: object 'input' not found**. I'm not sure why this is happening. I've tried making input$decompselect reactive, but then it says the reactive variable is not found. Does anyone know what's going on?

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(regclass)
library(fpp3)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("decompselect", "Choose variable", names(aus_production)),
  plotOutput("decomp")
)

server <- function(input,output){
  
  
  
  output$decomp <- renderPlot({
    
    aus_production %>%
      model(x11 = X_13ARIMA_SEATS(input$decompselect~ x11())) %>%
      components() %>% autoplot()
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: if you replace the code inside `renderplot({...})` with just `print(input$decompselect)`, do you still get the same error?

Comment: No, I don't. I think the issue has something to do with the decomposition model, but I'm not sure what

Comment: have you tried writing input$decompselect to a temp variable and using that in your model?

Comment: I've never created a temp variable before. i would use tempvar() correct?

Comment: just add a line `tmp <- input$decompselect` above `aus_production %>%...` and then replace `X_13ARIMA_SEATS(input$decompselect~ x11()))` with `X_13ARIMA_SEATS(tmp~ x11()))`

Comment: That doesn't work either. It says Error in FUN: object 'tmp' not found, so it seems like the same issue

Comment: here is the solution! ```library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(regclass)
library(fpp3)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("decompselect", "Choose variable", names(aus_production)),
  plotOutput("decomp")
)

server <- function(input,output){
  
  
  form <- reactive({
    formula(paste(input$decompselect,"~x11()"))
  })
  
  
  output$decomp <- renderPlot({
    
    aus_production %>%
      model(x11 = X_13ARIMA_SEATS( formula(form()))) %>%
      components() %>% autoplot()
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)```